Instantiate a prefab in order of a list
I'm having trouble with prefab order in a parental container. Being given a list having ids of the 3d models that we have posted them into database, now, I'm using the id to load them into our game.
But the problem I'm having is that some of them will have a different loading and cloning time, so the order of these prefabs in the container is wrong.
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
 
 
public class LoadModelManager:MonoBehaviour {
    static public IEnumerator LoadModel( int? id, GameObject self, GameObject parent = null, bool active = false, int indexOrder=0)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            id = 0; // skin default
        }
        string url = $"{GlobalVariable.server_url}/3ds/download/{id}"; // Replace with your server and image id
   
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
 
            if (webRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(webRequest.error);
            }
            else
            {
               AssetBundle  remoteAssetBundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(webRequest);
 
               if (remoteAssetBundle == null){
                yield break;
               }
 
                Debug.Log(remoteAssetBundle.LoadAsset(remoteAssetBundle.GetAllAssetNames()[0]));
               var model = Instantiate(remoteAssetBundle.LoadAsset(remoteAssetBundle.GetAllAssetNames()[0])) as GameObject;
           
                model.transform.position = self.transform.position;
                model.transform.rotation = self.transform.rotation;
                model.transform.localScale = self.transform.localScale;
 
                if (parent !=null){
                model.transform.SetParent(parent.transform,false);
                }
                if (indexOrder!=0){
                model.transform.SetSiblingIndex(indexOrder);
                }
                if (active == true){
                    model.SetActive(true);
                }
                else {
                         model.SetActive(false);
                }
               remoteAssetBundle.Unload(false);
            }
        }
    }
   
   
 
}

I have tried to use SetSiblingIndex but seems like it still gives wrong order.
If anyone has solved this problem, please let me know how to solve this. I will be really appreciated.
Thank you. Have a nice day!

You should set the indexOrder default to -1, since 0 is a valid index.  Please provide the details of what order you expect and the order you get.

my hierachy come in like this
prototype (which has the transform of the 3d model I want and set inactive)

SetSiblingIndex is the way to go, but you will have to set it after all are parented.
